# Why am i getting WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied?

Tags: python, program-files, windowserror

Trying to create program that adds folders into program files-recieving this error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied 'C:\\Program Files\\IMP'
```

Here is my code

```
import os, sys, random
numb= 1
x=True
while x==True:
    newpath = ((r'C:\Program Files\IMP\folder_%s') % (numb))
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
    numb=numb+1
    if numb==11:
        x=False
```

Comment: do you have write permissions?

Answer (score 17):

Because you have to have the "system administrator privileges" to create dirs under `C:\Program Files`.

So try run the script with system administrators privilege.

---

To start a command prompt as an administrator

1. Click Start.
2. In the Start Search box, type `cmd`, and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. Run the python script.

Comment: Use an administrator command prompt and then run the script again.

Comment: Is there a way to setup command prompt so that a "user command prompt" always starts up with particular privileges that administrator command prompts have? (Like the privileges that allow a user command prompt to install python modules using pip)

Comment: @Minh Tran I guess you could make a batch script to runas administrator. That'd be pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file (which file/folder's permissions needed to execute the script) go properties, security and enable all permissions, little checkboxes -> ALLOW: "every application package & limited application package & trusted installer"

this is it :)

Comment: This looks like a pretty good answer, but could be improved with explaining what you see as the cause of the problem, and why you think this will solve it.