# Python subprocess access denied

Tags: python, permissions, subprocess, installation

I am trying to install java silently in the background using a python script. The path is correct and verified with isfile. I recieve an Access Denied exception. I am running this as an administrator on my local machine.

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\Users\xUser\jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"');
```

error returns

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: You have some un-escaped backslashes in that path. Don't think that would cause the error, but it might be worth prepending the string with an **r**: **r'C\Users\...'** so it is interpreted as a raw string.

Comment: related: [Why am i getting WindowsError: [Error 5\] Access is denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28528020/4279). Make sure `import getpass; print(getpass.getuser())` prints the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this in a regular terminal? In Windows, you need to open the terminal specially for administrative privileges:

1. In the Start menu search window, type cmd and press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`. Or, navigate to All Programs > Accessories > right click on Command Prompt and click `Run as administrator`.
2. Run the python script in this new terminal.

Edit: a search yields it also may be an issue with executing the command after navigating to the directory the installer is located in; see [WindowsError [error 5] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005437/windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied).

```
install_dir=r"C:\Users\xUser\"
assert os.path.isdir(install_dir)
os.chdir(install_dir)
subprocess.Popen('jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"')
```

Finally, I always use an array of commands for Unix (not sure if it's required in Windows), not one long string, e.g.

`subprocess.Popen(['jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe', '/s', 'ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature"'])`.

Comment: So I actually have tried that. I can run C:\Users\xUser\jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature" from the command line as an administrator already. I just see the issue with subprocess within the script

Comment: Closer! only this issue now ::::: 

   assert os.path.isdir(install_dir)
AssertionError

Comment: Did you include the `r` before `"C:\Users\xUser\"`?

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: Okay, so now you are getting the file to actually run. This error means you do not have the correct privileges/permissions. So make sure that you are now running this python script in a command prompt that was opened as an administrator.