# Running Spark on Windows Error 5 (Access Denied) even when running as Admin

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, windowserror

I'm beginning with Spark so not really sure where my problem is and looking for a helpful hint here. I'm trying to run Spark (pyspark) on a windows 7 machine as an admin but it does not seem to be working (I still get the WindowsError 5). See image below:

[image]

I've downloaded the file (release 1.2.0 with pre-built for Hadoop 2.4 or later), unzipped it using tar via command line and set IPYTHON=1 before calling bin\pyspark. When I call it, pyspark runs but I get the error below as per image.

When I try calling certain SparkContext objects, I get name 'sc' is not defined.

I've got python 2.7.8 installed, Spyder IDE and am in a corporate network environment.

Does any one have a clue what could be going on here? I've looked up a few questions such as [Why am i getting WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528020/why-am-i-getting-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied) but could not find a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly:

I had what should be the same problem. For me, it was that the `*.cmd` files in the `$spark/bin` directory weren't marked as executable; please try to confirm by:

- right clicking on `pyspark2.cmd` and:
- properties / security tab then examine 'Read & execute'

I found the workaround on another site, that recommended downloading `hadoop-winutils-2.6.0.zip` (sorry don't have a link). Here is an example of the cmd to use (after moving to proper directory):

```
t:\hadoop-winutils-2.6.0\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 *
```

I did need to run the `chmod 777` cmd to make the `/tmp/hive` writeable too.
good luck!

(... new here - sorry for the poor formatting)
(update: Matt thanks for fixing formatting issues!)

**root cause**: the tar program i used on windows via `tar -zxf <file.tgz>` did not apply 
the proper attributes to the extracted files.  in this case the 'executable' files
weren't properly set. yeah, maybe i should update my version of cygwin.