# Apache-spark - Error launching pyspark on windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark on windows. However, I received following error:

```
c:\spark>pyspark
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\spark\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 38, in <module>
   SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 259, in _ensure_initialized
   SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 80, in launch_gateway
   proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
File "C:\Users\shuzhe\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\shuzhe\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I have searched for hours, but I could not find a solution to this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I ran into the same problem.  I ditched the `SPARK_HOME` folder (which in my case was `C:\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7`) that I created previously using `cygwin tar` and tried unpacking the folder again (from `spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`), but this time using `7zip` instead of `cygwin tar` and then problem went away.  Note that with `7zip` the unpacking is done in two step, first extract the `...tar` from `...tgz`, and then extract the whole directory tree from `...tar`

Some other discussion on the Internet (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356359/1168041)) suggested that the problem was due to `cygwin tar` got some permission wrong.  This explanation is consistent with what I tested and experienced above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spark 2.1 you will have to switch to spark 2.1.1.There is a bug with python 3.6 and now is resolved in 2.1.1 .

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019\

I had same problem with python 3.6 and 3.5 and spark 2.1 on windows , and I switched to anaconda python 2.7 and now it works fine.

Comment: Hi. Actually I used spark 2.1.1, and this problem still exists. So do you have any other ideas about what should i do?

Comment: Sorry , I installed 2.1.1  spark , with same anaconda version 4.3.1 ,windows 10 , and java 1.8.0_131-b11 and hadoop 2.7.3  ,winutils 2.7.1   and i could't get same error as you.