# writing dataset<Row> to excel is giving ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied ERROR

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-excel

I have created a dataset of type `Row` as below,

```
Dataset<Row> databaseDs = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dbStatus, Status.class);
```

I want to convert this to Excel sheet so I used below code for Excel conversion

```
databaseDs.write()
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("addColorColumns", "false").mode("overwrite").save("C:\\resultset.xlsx");
```

But I am getting

> ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied

How to resolve this issue as I have the permission to write to `c:` folder and still empty files ".resultset.xlsx.crc" and "resultset.xlsx" with 0kb

Comment: You dont have permission write under the C folder. Change the path to some other drive or mention hadoop user as part of system . Make sure the user mentioning can have write access or create a folder under c and provide all permission to that folder and write under it

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: ChangeFileModeByMask error (5): Access is denied. I am still getting the error after creating new folder and giving all permissions. how to create hadoop user as part of system?

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168135/running-spark-on-windows-error-5-access-denied-even-when-running-as-admin

Comment: tried with no luck... :::::::::::(